# count variable php no database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a script but I am a little hard how to count the data I can be of variable

example :

```
<?php
    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Jakarta');
    $u = $row->jadwalkal;
    $tgl1 = $u;
    $tgl2 = date("Y-m-d");
    $selisih = strtotime($tgl1) -  strtotime($tgl2);
    $hari = $selisih/(60*60*24);
        if ($hari < 0) {  ?>
          <?php echo "Telat $hari  hari";?></div>
       <?php}elseif ($hari < 7) { ?>
          <?php echo "Tinggal $hari hari";?></div>
       <?php }else { ?>
         <?php echo "Masih $hari hari";?></div>
      <?php } ?>
```

how to calculate the results of **$hari**

result : count  $hari < 7 // ??

result : count  $hari < 0 // ??

result : count  $hari  // ??

Comment: `$hari` has already the result of the division. Did you even try to run the script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The above code has following error:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in file on line 10

Modify your code as below:

```
<?php
    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Jakarta');
    $u = $row->jadwalkal;
    $tgl1 = $u;
    $tgl2 = date("Y-m-d");
    $selisih = strtotime($tgl1) -  strtotime($tgl2);
    $hari = $selisih/(60*60*24);
        if ($hari < 0) {  ?>
          <?php echo "Telat $hari  hari";?></div>
       <?php } elseif ($hari < 7) { ?>
          <?php echo "Tinggal $hari hari";?></div>
       <?php }else { ?>
         <?php echo "Masih $hari hari";?></div>
      <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

your code is having some syntax issues

```
<?php}elseif
```

modify as shown

```
<?php } elseif
```

Answer (score -1):

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Jakarta');
$u       = $row->jadwalkal;
$tgl1    = $u;
$tgl2    = date("Y-m-d");
$selisih = strtotime($tgl1) -  strtotime($tgl2);
$hari    = $selisih/(60*60*24);

$c1 = 0;
$c2 = 0;
$c3 = 0;

if ($hari < 0) {
    echo "Telat $hari  hari";
    $c1++;
}
elseif ($hari < 7) {
    echo "Tinggal $hari hari";
    $c2++;
}
else {
    echo "Masih $hari hari";
    $c3++;
}

echo $c1."<br>".$c2."<br>".$c3."<br>";
```

Comment: okay this run , but I want the count of data of all the table columns,ex.. how many $hari > 0 in tables?